# Understanding of code

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview

I have a project that is written from another developer and inside `didSelectAnnotationView` there are following lines of code:

I can't understand why he uses the lines after `height`
I also commented them and nothing changed.

```
let mapMarker = view.annotation as! MapMaker
self.selMapMarker = mapMarker;

let selectedAnnoView = self.selMapMarker.view

if selectedAnnoView != nil {

    selectedAnnoView?.image = nil;
    selectedAnnoView?.image = UIImage(named: self.selMapMarker.nameImage)
}

var height = (selectedAnnoView?.frame.size.height)! + 10.0;
height = height / mapView.frame.size.height;
height  = 1.0 - height / 2.0;


let markerPoint = self.mapView.convertCoordinate(mapMarker.coordinate, toPointToView: self.mapView);
var mapFrame = self.mapView.convertRegion(self.mapView.region, toRectToView: self.mapView);
mapFrame.origin.y = markerPoint.y - mapFrame.size.height * height;
mapFrame.origin.x = markerPoint.x - mapFrame.size.width / 2.0;
```

Can anyone understand what could they do or there are not much information?

Comment: Looks like he is trying to centre the map for the selected annotation.

Comment: @iphonic thanks for your comment